# 7 Day Trial Balance Query - must be a better way

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, legacy

I have the following TSQL query from a SSRS report that queries a warehouse management system that we are currently running.  Is there a better way to write this query?  There must be a better way to write this type of query but at the moment I just can't see it.

The query puts the outstanding invoice amounts into weekly columns.

```
SELECT ContCode, TradingName, DaysFromInvoice, CreditLimit,
    CASE WHEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+]
        WHEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42]
        WHEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35]
        WHEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28]
        WHEN [8-14] + [15-21] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21]
        WHEN [8-14] < 0 THEN [0-7] + [8-14]
        WHEN [0-7] = 0 AND [0-7] + [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] = 0 AND Total <> 0 THEN Total 
        ELSE [0-7] END [0-7],  
    CASE WHEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0
        WHEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] >= 0 THEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+]
        WHEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] >= 0 THEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42]
        WHEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] >= 0 THEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35]
        WHEN [15-21] + [22-28] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28] >= 0 THEN [8-14] + [15-21] + [22-28]
        WHEN [15-21] < 0 AND [8-14] + [15-21] >= 0 THEN [8-14] + [15-21]
        WHEN [8-14] < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [8-14] END [8-14],  
    CASE WHEN [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0
        WHEN [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] >= 0 THEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+]
        WHEN [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] < 0 AND [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] >= 0 THEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42]
        WHEN [22-28] + [29-35] < 0 AND [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35] >= 0 THEN [15-21] + [22-28] + [29-35]
        WHEN [22-28] < 0 AND [15-21] + [22-28] >= 0 THEN [15-21] + [22-28]
        WHEN [15-21] < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [15-21] END [15-21],  
    CASE WHEN [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0
        WHEN [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] >= 0 THEN [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+]
        WHEN [29-35] + [36-42] < 0 AND [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42] >= 0 THEN [22-28] + [29-35] + [36-42]
        WHEN [29-35] < 0 AND [22-28] + [29-35] >= 0 THEN [22-28] + [29-35]
        WHEN [22-28] < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [22-28] END [22-28],  
    CASE WHEN [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0
        WHEN [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+] >= 0 THEN [29-35] + [36-42] + [43+]
        WHEN [36-42] < 0 AND [29-35] + [36-42] >= 0 THEN [29-35] + [36-42]
        WHEN [29-35] < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE [29-35] END [29-35], 
    CASE WHEN [36-42] + [43+] < 0 AND [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0
        WHEN [36-42] + [43+] < 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN [43+] < 0 THEN [36-42] + [43+]
        ELSE [36-42] END [36-42], 
    CASE WHEN [43+] < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [43+] END [43+],
    Total
FROM
(
    SELECT ContGnrl.ContCode,ContGnrl.TradingName,ContBals.DaysFromInvoice, ContAcct.CreditLimit,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) < 8 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [0-7],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) BETWEEN 8 AND 14 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [8-14],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [15-21],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) BETWEEN 22 AND 28 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [22-28],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) BETWEEN 29 AND 35 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [29-35],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) BETWEEN 36 AND 42 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [36-42],
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, ContTran.TranDate, cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) as datetime)) >= 43 AND ContTran.TranType <> 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) 
        + COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ContTran.TranType = 'P' THEN ContTran.Outstanding END), 0) [43+],
        COALESCE(SUM(ContTran.Outstanding), 0) Total
    FROM ContGnrl 
        JOIN ContBals 
            ON ContGnrl.ContCode = ContBals.ContCode 
        JOIN ContAcct 
            ON ContBals.ContCode = ContAcct.ContCode 
        LEFT JOIN ContTran
            ON ContGnrl.ContCode = ContTran.ContCode
                AND (ContTran.Finalised = 0) 
                AND (ContTran.TranType IN ('I','C','J','P','D'))

    GROUP BY ContGnrl.ContCode,ContGnrl.TradingName,ContBals.DaysFromInvoice, ContAcct.CreditLimit
    HAVING COALESCE(SUM(ContTran.Outstanding), 0) <> 0
) t
ORDER BY TradingName
```

Comment: Why don't you aggregate in your application? Business logic in the database is often not the best idea, and here clearly the design of the report is hitting the database layer. Moving the aggregation up to the application has the added benefit of being able to change the aggregation on the fly without hitting the database again, which is especially problematic if the query is unoptimized and running against production systems.

Comment: yea, that would be nice but it's a 3rd party legacy application that we don't have the source code for.  It will be replaced in the not to distant future so this is a stop gap measure  for now.

Comment: So you can change the SQL query but not the application receiving the data. Do you want to achieve anything specific? Is the query too slow? Is the database load too heavy? You could easily transform it into a table-valued function, if you wanted to optimize without cracking the interface.

Comment: The query is used in an SSRS report that connects directly to the SQL-Server database of the application.  We needed a number of reports that the application did not provide.  The query run fine as it is but I will need to extend it to more weeks and was hoping that other people may have though of a better way of writing the same query

Comment: I would balk at this because there can be a number of things going in the mix above. I am not balking at answering your original post. After looking at your requirements I would put the less amount of sql results to get the most amount of useful data to a client that continue your further processing.

Comment: I guess it's going to be a trade off between doing most of the processing in TSQL or in SSRS in my case. For the moment i'm not looking for a final answer per sae but to write the query in a much more concise and readable way.